# CoreBluetooth Receive notifications in CBPeripheralManager

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm implementing CBPeripheralManager on my iPhone running iOS6 and I have created and added a custom service and characteristic.  An external Bluetooth Device (the BLE112, if it makes a difference) acts as the Central and starts writing data to the characteristic I have implemented.  I know it's being written because a test application on the App Store (light blue) sees it as being written, but I'm just not sure how to see it from the CBPeripheralManager.  didReceiveWriteRequests is never called, and the "value" property on my characteristic variable is never called either.  So, to sum up, my question is: From the CBPeripheralManager, how can I tell when updates to a characteristic have been written from a central?

Comment: Did you set the `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` ?

Comment: Yep, I set the delegate. didReceiveWriteRequests is called when I write to the characteristic from another iOS Device, but not when I write to it from the BLE112.  I would say it's a problem with 112 code, but the LightBlue app from the app store still sees the updates somehow.  Is there a way to see writes without going through the didReceiveWriteRequests method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through much trial and error, I found that under the Service property for the iOS side, you need to create it with "CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite" instead of "CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse" in order to get didReceiveWriteRequests.  Seems obvious, but kept me scratching my head for a while.

Comment: You should still get the didReceiveWriteRequests in both cases.  The difference is that when the peripheral processes a write request expecting a response it should call "[_peripheralMgr respondToRequest: request  withResult: result];"  This call is not made if the write request is not expecting a response.

Comment: It depends on how you write from the central. If you write `CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse` then you have to setup your peripheral like this. You can also respond to both types by using the ` | ` symbol.